# How to not cache configurable product options block?

Tags: layout, cache, magento2.4

On the product display page for a configurable product, what block (via the layout .xml files) do I need to mark as `cacheable="false"` so that the dropdowns of options (e.g. size / colour) do not get cached?

Answer (score 0):

Cacheable and uncacheable are terms we use to indicate whether or not a page should be cached at all. (By default, all pages are cacheable.) If any block in a layout is designated as uncacheable, the entire page is uncacheable.

To create an uncacheable page, mark any block on that page as uncacheable in the layout using cacheable="false".

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit" name="customer_edit" template="Magento_Customer::form/edit.phtml" cacheable="false">
<container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
```

Examples of uncacheable pages include the compare products, cart, checkout pages, and so on.
Do not configure content pages (i.e., catalog, product, and CMS pages) to be uncacheable. Doing so harms performance.
Reverse proxies serve “public” or shared content to more than one user. However, most Magento websites generate dynamic and personalized “private” content that should only be served to one user, which presents unique caching challenges. To address these challenges, Magento can distinguish between two types of content:

Public - Public content is stored server-side in your reverse proxy cache storage (e.g., file system, database, Redis, or Varnish) and is available to multiple customers. Examples of public content include header, footer, and category listing.

Private - Private content is stored client-side (e.g., browser) and is specific to an individual customer. Examples of private content include wishlist, shopping cart, customer name, and address. You should limit stored private content to a small portion of the page’s total content.

Comment: Whilst it is true that the full page will no longer be cacheable, I am also looking to make the individual block not cache as well. There are multiple cache types, "block_html" and "full_page" are just two of them, and while the full page cache may be turned off on the product page, the block html cache is still caching the options that I don't want to see between users. What block do I need to set as cacheable=false in order to see the custom pricing changes (custom module) on configurable options?